# printf won't PRINT in if statement, specifically the gender variable

Tags: if-statement

Below I have some code that asks for the users gender to enter a website, issue is I placed a `printf()` function to display a message of the user's gender inside of an if statement and now it does not print.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int age;
    char gender;

    printf("How old are you? \n");
    scanf_s(" %d", &age);

    printf("What is your gender \n");
    scanf_s(" %c", &gender);

    if (age >= 18) {
        printf("You may enter this website ");
    }

        if (gender == 'f') {
            printf("m'lady");
        }

        if (gender == 'm') {
            printf("dude");
        }

    if (age < 18){
        printf("Nothing to see here!");
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what is the `scanf_s` function? Does your compiler compile the code?

Comment: I've been told scanf_s is safer to avoid crashes and better than scanf. The "s" stand for safety but I'll try it with old scanf.

Comment: does it compile? What inputs do you use? What does it print?

Comment: It works for me. Do you give the inputs at the same time?

Comment: It compiles. I use lower case letters: 'm' and 'f'. And it printf() out "you may enter this website" but it doesn't printf() "dude" or "m'lady". And I do one input at a time. Though, I switched to scanf() and it worked, but it doesn't work with scanf_s().